# ros2 unit testing

Tags: ros, ros2, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am new to automated testing and I find it quite difficult to find a resource to write my first unit test for CPP files. Is there a tutorial with the general procedure (What commands?: just `colcon test`??, How should the Cmakelists.txt and the test.cpp look like?) or a minimal framework I can have a look at?

I would really appreciate the help.
Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403428/ros2-unit-testing/) by [MaxDio](https://answers.ros.org/users/105799/maxdio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try to base your tests on the `nav2_system_tests` [like there](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_system_tests/), they use `gtests`.

E.g. planning folder has a nice example here:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_system_tests/src/planning/test_planner_costmaps_node.cpp

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0